# Does the following set span $R^3$ and is it a basis of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\left\{ \left( 1,1,1 \right), \left( 0,1,1 \right), \left( 0,0,1 \right), \left( 1,2,3 \right) \right\}$

The first thing I did was test for linear independence:

$x=(0,0,0)$ $u=(1,1,1)$ $v=(0,1,1)$ $w=(0,0,1)$  $q=(1,2,3)$

So $x = c_1u+c_2v+c_3w+c_4q$

This then gives the matrix:

$A=$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$

The $rref(A)$ shows a linearly independent set.  But I'm not sure how to test if it spans $R^3$?  If I can determine if it spans $R^3$ I will the know if this is a basis of $R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

First, plug the vectors into a matrix as columns (or rows).  If you plugged them in as columns, find the column space.  If you plugged them in as rows, then carry out row reduction to find the row space.

If the column space or the row space has dimension $<3$, then they cannot form a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Note that, if you have $x$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $x>n$, then the set of vectors is *never* linearly independent, and thus cannot be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, if your vectors are a spanning set, then a subset of them *will* be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a basis, they're linearly-dependent. If $m>n$ then you can't have $m$ linearly-independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

About spanning, let me give you a hint first. Can you relate this problem to linear equations and determinants?

Comment: How did you determine that at the vectors are linearly dependent aside from recognizing the rule of $m > n$?  Also, would it be $m < n$?  To address the hint, I cannot calculate the determinant because the matrix is not square.

Comment: @inquisitor: I know that determinants are defined for square matrices, but you can still use them. For example, you can choose three vectors out of the four given vectors and show that they form a basis. If three of them span the space, then adding a new vector won't cause any troubles. About linear independence, what do you mean by "Also, would it be m<n"? I didn't get what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

That is, you can write one of the given vectors as a linear combination of the other three. And as a result, the *four* vectors are *not* linearly independent after all.

But, the most obvious point is that no set of $m$ linearly independent vectors can be a basis for a space of dimension $n$ when $m>n$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally if a vector space $E$ can be generated by $p$ vectors then we can not find a family of $q$ linearly independent  vectors in $E$ with $q>p$. That is, a linearly independent family of vectors in $E$ can not have more vectors than **any** generating family of vectors in $E$.

In our example $\mathbb R^3$ can be generated by the canonical basis consisting of the three vectors 
$$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$$
Hence any set of linearly independent vectors of  $\mathbb R^3$ must contain at most $3$ vectors. Here we have $4$ vectors than they are necessarily linearly dependent.

To find out which of these $4$ vectors are linearly independent we proceed by row reducing the matrix whose columns are the $4$ given vectors. With this reduction we will know the pivot columns from which we know which of the $4$ vectors are linearly independent. If we find three of them are linearly independent then these three are necessarily a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.